# Trigger Sidebar from two different button using State in React && styled-components

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

**The first button:**

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <SideCart open={open} />
      <CartButton open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
      )
    </>
```

**The sidebar:**

```
const [hide, setHide] = useState(open ? true : true);
  return (
    <SidecartContainer open={open} hide={hide}>

       // Thats the second button 
       // I want to close the sidebar component with this button
      <ExitButton hide={hide} onClick={() => setHide(!hide)}>
    </SidecartContainer>

const SidecartContainer = styled.div`
  transform: ${({ open, hide }) =>
    open && hide ? "translateX(0)" : "translateX(100%)"};
`;
```

I have one button triggering the Open state of sidebar and when it opens I have an x button to close the sidebar.

It only works once.

What shall I use so whenever I click the open button to open and then when I click on close to hide?

It's made with styled-components.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that this line `const [hide, setHide] = useState(open ? true : true);` only runs once on component mount. What you need is a `useEffect` in the sidebar to listen for changes to `open` and apply them to the `hide` state like so:

```js
const [hide, setHide] = useState(open ? true : true);

useEffect(() => {
  setHide(!open);
}, [open]);

  return (
    <SidecartContainer open={open} hide={hide}>

--------Thats the second button 
--------I want to close the sidebar component with this button
      <ExitButton hide={hide} onClick={() => setHide(!hide)}>


    </SidecartContainer>
```

Comment: Nop that didn't really work..Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what's the right way to do it and it works.

First I declared outside of the sidebar the useStates logic:

```
  const [open, setOpen] = useState("");
  const hide = () => setOpen("translateX(100%)");
  const show = () => setOpen("translateX(0)");
```

then I passed the props to Sidecart.js:

```
const SideCart = (props) => {
  return (
    <SidecartContainer transform={props.transform} open={props.open}>
      <ExitButton open={props.open} onClick={props.onClick}>
        <CloseIcon />
      </ExitButton>
      <ProductCards>
        <CartProductCard />
      </ProductCards>
      <Total></Total>
    </SidecartContainer>
  );
};
```

also this is important, in the styled component css I declared the prop value:

```
const SidecartContainer = styled.div`
  transform: ${(props) => props.transform};
`;
```

Finally I changed the onClick functions accordingly:

```
  <SideCart transform={open} open={open} onClick={hide} />
  <CartButton open={open} onClick={show}>
```